# How can I call api directly from external http?

Tags: api, ajax

According to https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v3/rest :

> "As of v5.47+, there should be no reason to use extern/rest.php -
> other end-points should be more compatible and more featureful. See
> APIv3 Changelog for migration notes."

but a simple http request like:

> https://agloa.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/rest&entity=Contact&action=get&json=1&key=site_key&api_key=my_key

results in

> Ajax requests can only be issued by JavaScript clients, eg. CRM.api3

Does this mean I need to create a JavaScript client as a front-end to my http call?

Comment: Does the user with that api key have permission Use Ajax Api?

Comment: Yes, the user with that api key does have permission Use Ajax Api.

Comment: Do you have the authx extension installed? It changes things a bit - see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/authx/#flows, especially at the bottom where you can relax the settings to see if that's the problem.

Comment: I do have  the authx extension installed.  Relax the settings does not seem to resolve the problem.

Comment: I just realized the url I'm using forces me to log into my WordPress site before continuing. (As a result, the authx flow is 'already logged in.' That's why it decides my request is not a web service request.)

This is actually a bigger problem for me. Being forced to log in defeats the purpose.

Comment: Oh right wordpress - see if this helps: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v3/wp-rest/

Comment: This GET request is working for now, but I'll probably have to change it to a POST in order to use parameters.

https://agloa.org/wp-json/civicrm/v3/rest?entity=Contact&action=get&json=1&key=

Answer (score 2):

This URL lets me get contacts from my site externally (without logging in) and without creating a JavaScript client:
https://agloa.org/wp-json/civicrm/v3/rest?entity=Contact&action=get&json=1&key=<site_key>&apiKey=<my_key>

Comment: Thanks - searching for how to use the API and this definitely did the trick for me.